# overlay box working in firefox, but not iexplorer

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a webpage consisting of an overlay box that is activated when the website is first viewed.  The visitor would then click close on the overlay box and see the rest of the website.

What I have works perfectly in firefox.  But in iexplorer, it causes iexplorer to give the following error:- "Internet Explorer prevented this page from running scripts or ActiveX controls."

How can I modify it so that iexplorer does not give this error, and loads the page correctly.

Here is the html:-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<style>
#facebox {

/* overlay is hidden before loading */
display:none;

/* standard decorations */
width:400px;
border:10px solid #666;

/* for modern browsers use semi-transparent color on the border. nice! */
border:10px solid rgba(82, 82, 82, 0.698);

/* hot CSS3 features for mozilla and webkit-based browsers (rounded borders) */
-moz-border-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-radius:8px;
  }

  #facebox div {
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #3B5998;
    background-color:#fff;
    font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif
  }

  #facebox h2 {
    margin:-11px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#6D84B4;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #3B5998;
    font-size:20px;
  }
  </style>




</head>

<body>


<div class="main-content">

    <!-- Your Content Here -->

<p>Content</p>

</div>




<!-- facebook dialog -->
<div id="facebox">
  <div>
    <h2>Facebox</h2>
    <p>
      This dialog is opened programmatically when the page
      loads. There is no need for a trigger element.
    </p>
    <form>
      <input type="file" />
    </form>
    <p style="color:#666">
      To close, click the Close button or hit the ESC key.
    </p>
    <!-- yes/no buttons -->
    <p>
      <button class="close"> Close </button>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#open_now").click(function() {
      $("#facebox").overlay().load();
  });

    // select the overlay element - and "make it an overlay"
  $("#facebox").overlay({

    // custom top position
    top: 60,

    // some mask tweaks suitable for facebox-looking dialogs
    mask: {

    // you might also consider a "transparent" color for the mask
    color: '#000',

    // load mask a little faster
    loadSpeed: 200,

    // very transparent
    opacity: 0.5
    },

    // disable this for modal dialog-type of overlays
    closeOnClick: false,

    // load it immediately after the construction
    load: true

    });
    });
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What version of IE are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

This problem only occurs when you run your project locally. If you upload your project to a server and display the page, you should not have this error.